# Easy 3D animation inside wxpython widget

Tags: python, 3d, wxpython, mayavi, python-visual

I need to display simple 3D objects (box, cylinder, arrows, etc.) and move them in response to external signals (from an Arduino board). I am using wxpython for the main program, therefore, I would need something that can be included in a wx widget of some kind. 
These are the solutions that I have explored so far:

1. **Python-visual**. This solution would be perfect if I could use it in a wx widget. It has a very simple api, easy animation method, etc. Unfortunately, although it is now based on wx, it can not be inserted inside a generic wx frame. Moreover, it seems that there is no recent Linux package. The home page suggest to run the windows version on wine. Not what I am looking for.
2. **Mayavi** and **tvtk**. There is a visual module inside tvtk with an api very similar to python-visual. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the wxpython 3.0 I have on my ubuntu 14.10.
3. **Matplotlib**. I tried to use art3D module, but I couldn't find any implementation of basic solids (e.g. Cube, sphere, etc.). Only 2D patches (polygons).
4. **Vispy** and **visvis**. The first one is not usable yet and the second is not developed any more.
5. Opengl bindings and wrappers of different kinds.  They are to difficult to use.  I would need something more simple.

What I am missing? Is there a simple solution? 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with mayavi? I use mayavi in traitsui with wx under the hood. Typically, the largest problem with this is that it isn't easy to install or configure wxpython because it doesn't always come with the major scientific python distributions. But you seem to have it working, so I don't know what is the reason it doesn't work, maybe you can elaborate.

Comment: I don't remember the specific error message. But now I downgraded to wx 2.8 and now it seems to work.